# Socket server has endless loop after second pass (C++/Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int socketfd = 0;
    int portin = 5514; //default port
    int que = 20; //default queue size
    int n = 0;
    int d = 1; //for use in setsockopt
    socklen_t clientsize = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in servadd, cliadd;
    if (argc > 2)
        portin = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (argc > 1)
        que = atoi(argv[1]);
    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &d, sizeof(int));
    bzero((char*) &servadd, sizeof(servadd));
    servadd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servadd.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servadd.sin_port = htons(portin);
    bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servadd, sizeof(servadd));
    std::cout << "Wall server running on port " << portin << " with queue size " << que << ".\n";
    char wallc[] = "Wall Contents\n-------------\n";
    char entc[] = "Enter command: ";
    do {
        listen(socketfd,1);
        clientsize = sizeof(cliadd);
        int newadd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliadd, &clientsize);
        while (newadd > 0) {
            char buffer[80];
            n = write(newadd, wallc, sizeof(wallc));
            n = write(newadd, entc, strlen(entc));
            int a = recv(newadd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); //this blocks for input on first and 
// second pass, but on third, it will just skip over and cause endless output from write commands.
            memset(buffer, 0, 80);
        };
    }while (socketfd > 0);
    return 0;
}
```

This code, when ran in one terminal and connected to with another, will output both buffers to the client terminal. It will then wait for a command the first time through the loop, and will then comeback to the recv command the second time in the loop, but no matter the input, after entering the second time, it will endlessly write the two buffers to the client terminal until I turn it off. There's other functionality in the full code that makes this server a bulletin board system, but this block of code here, when ran, is what gives me the endless loop and I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Rule one of network programing: Always fully evaluate the return codes.

Comment: `strlen(buffer)` is not the correct way to get the size of a buffer. `strlen` searches for the first null character it can find . This implies that the buffer must have a null character within its bounds, something this program cannot guarantee. Also consider what happens when the first character happens to be the null character. Use `sizeof(buffer)`

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your help, that solved the infinite loop problem, although I am getting interesting behavior in that to get proper input I need to trim two characters off the end of the buffer the first time, and only one each successive time.

Comment: No one has answered the question yet so it should be safe for you to update the code with what you have now. There are a LOT of little omissions in the error checking in what you have posted so far that could account for the new problem. If you've corrected some of them in the meantime, it's information we need to have to be any help short of rewriting the code, something you probably won't learn much from.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments, as posted by @user4581301 :
`strlen(buffer)` is not the correct way to get the size of a buffer. `strlen` searches for the first null character it can find . This implies that the buffer must have a null character within its bounds, something this program cannot guarantee. Also consider what happens when the first character happens to be the null character. Use `sizeof(buffer)`.

So, in short, don't do what I did. Use `sizeof`, not `strlen`.